# How to utilize SSL Validation in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I am trying to utilize a trusted Cert, and wanted to see if the following code does work. I don't take any ownership for this code, but just wanted to see how to call this delegate. I have set my connect as self delegate, but it never call's this method.

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *) space {
if([[space authenticationMethod] 
isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
// Note: this is presently only called once per server (or URL?) until
//       you restart the app
if(shouldAllowSelfSignedCert) {
return YES; // Self-signed cert will be accepted
} else {
return NO;  // Self-signed cert will be rejected
}
// Note: it doesn't seem to matter what you return for a proper SSL cert
//       only self-signed certs
}
// If no other authentication is required, return NO for everything else
// Otherwise maybe YES for NSURLAuthenticationMethodDefault and etc.
return NO;
}
```

If anyone can point me out to the right direction I will really appreciate that.

Thanks.